# Field test on iPhone 7. Can't locate "rsrp0"

Tags: signal, signal-strength

I have an unlocked iPhone 7 on T-Mobile, model A1660 on IOS 14.0.1. I'm trying to find the cell signal strength by running the field test [as described here](https://www.macworld.com/article/3346027/how-to-see-your-true-cellular-signal-strength-with-the-iphone-field-test-app.html). From my reading, rsrp0 is the best option to get a realistic idea of the true cell signal strength. However when I click on the Serving Cell Measurements, instead of seeing a # of fields like "rsrp1", "rsrp0", etc, I get the below. **Would one of these fields (Measured RSRP perhaps?) provide equivalent information to rsrp0?**

[image: Serving Cell Measurements]

Comment: RSSI is probably what you're looking for.  That's the Received Signal Strength Indicator.  The other would be RSRP and RSRQ → Reference Signal Received Power and Received Quality, respectively.  Minimum should be -20, but lower is better.

Comment: I'm really just looking for something to indicate signal strength. I'm in the market for a cell phone booster for road trips and want a way to see the before/after.

Is RSSI appropriate for 4G LTE? From what I've read (and this may be way off since my networking knowledge is limited at best), RSSI is better suited to 3G.

My GF's phone (Galaxy S9) which is on the same plan/carrier and same location, is showing -99. I thought that would be comparable to RSRP on the iPhone, and it more or less is. However if her's is measuring RSSI, then my phone would have a massively better signal.

Comment: [RSSI is a *measurement* of radio signal strength](https://www.metageek.com/training/resources/understanding-rssi.html) it's not an option or a feature of LTE, 3G, etc.  We measure WiFi signals using RSSI as well.